# Forward declaration vs using class method

Tags: c++

I have such logics:

`GameMap` includes `Player`. `Player` includes `Entity` (which is a super class of `Player`). Both `Entity` and `Player` use a `GameMap` object.

```
// GameMap.h
#pragma once
#include "Player.h"
class GameMap
{
public:
    bool isTileSolid(GameMap & map, int tileX, int tileY);
};



// Player.h
#pragma once
#include "Entity.h"
class Player : public Entity
{
public:
    bool collides(GameMap & map);
};


// Entity.h
#pragma once
class GameMap; // Forward declaration instead of including GameMap.h (it would not even compile)
class Entity {
};




// Player.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Player.h"
bool Player::collides(GameMap & map)
{
    if (map.isTileSolid(map, 0, 0)) // BEEP! incomplete type not allowed
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

How can I make the method `isTileSolid(...)` work inside Player source file? Can I make some kind of forward declaration for the method as well?

Comment: Why isn't `Player.cpp` including `GameMap.h`?

Comment: Why do you need to pass a `GameMap` object into `isTileSolid` if that's already a method on a `GameMap`?

Comment: @Buddy It's possible that GameMap requires a 2nd GameMap, but I doubt that's the case. Maybe the function is supposed to be static and not inside the class?

Comment: @JamesAdkison Oh, okay, as a stupid Java lover I don't really understand the headers. Your answer helped.

Comment: @Buddy That's my mistake. Indeed, it shouldn't. I messed up something while rewriting the code so it doesn't show anything unnecessary here.